# azure function not connecting via DirectLine to bot framework

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-functions, direct-line-botframework

I am try to setup azure function with HTTP triggered and make subsequent call to azure bot framework [bot service on azure].

Following is the error i encountered while setting it up:

```
{
  "id": "ed81eca8-d536-4534-a97d-66e6a7ca7ad2",
  "requestId": "ba346904-702b-465c-b7e3-b48afe29ab33",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "messsage": "Exception while executing function: Functions.adapter -> Unable to resolve value for property 'BotAttribute.SecretSetting'."
}
```

Env:

- Nodejs dev
- Using `directline-JS` git repo at [BotFramework-DirectLineJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS)

Related questions:

- [Azure function doesn't notify my bot (Bot Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579703/azure-function-doesnt-notify-my-bot-bot-framework)
- [Azure Function for Bot Framework C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559322/azure-function-for-bot-framework-c-sharp)

Comment: Looking at the first linked question: do you have 'secret' set to the name of an app setting with your secret?

Comment: @MattMason-MSFT I found the solution. The secret was defined but i was returning value in a wrong way in azure function. i.e```context.done(done,data)``` where i was passing incoming data directly to output which did not hold secret, rather than modified version of data.

Answer (score 1):

The secret was defined but i was returning value in a wrong way in azure function. i.e `context.done(done,data)` where i was passing incoming data directly to output which did not hold secret, rather than modified version of data.

Comment: The error continues after having BotFramework as Input along with Output to the same bot.